# SQL Remove element from all columns on a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I have a table with around 30 columns all column title have **"**. I will like to know if on sql have a script to replace the *"* for none.

Example

```
"ID"  |"Color"  |"Size"  | "Price" ....
 1    |  Red    |  3     |$50.00
 2    |  Blue   |  5     |$30.00
```

And I will like to look like:

```
ID  | Color  | Size  | Price ....
1   | Red    |  3    | $50.00
2   | Blue   |  5    | $30.00
```

Comment: Don't store '$' !!

Answer (score 1):

Do like this for all columns:

```
ALTER TABLE blog RENAME COLUMN "ID" ID;
```

Comment: SQL have a form or way to do this  process one time and change all column name whit out mention the name of the column ?